# Android webview. Fitting HTML on screen without a scrollbar

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I was trying to learn  web view on Android. I have a few questions.

1. I have a PHP page, which has 2-3 small paragraphs and an Image which
   is randomly generated. How can I make sure that the whole HTML page
   fits perfectly on the mobile device’s screen (so that scroll bar
   isn’t seen)?  if it’s not possible in some instances that how can I
   make the image smaller so that it fits perfectly on every device ? .
2. Second question is suppose I have a link on that HTML page. I want
   that when I click this link (which belongs to a different domain) it
   open up in the default browser NOT the android Application. (How can
   this be done).

   package com.example.try2;

   ```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.view.WindowManager;
   import android.webkit.WebSettings;
   import android.webkit.WebView;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           //Full screen
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
           this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
           myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
           myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
           myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
           myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
           WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
           webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/mobile/index.php");

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. You may actually have to do this in the HTML / JS code. Hook the resize event and set the picture size based on the number of pixels available on that device. Here is an example in jQuery, where myImage is the id of your image and myText is the id of the div containing text at the top of the page:

   ```
   $(window).resize(function() {

       // Compute available height for image
       // by subtracting text div height from screen height
       var availableImageWidth = screen.width;
       var availableImageHeight = screen.height - $('myText').height();

       // Get image width and height
       var imageWidth = $("#myImage").width();
       var imageHeight = $("#myImage").height();

       // Compute scale that maintains aspect ratio and fits image within screen bounds
       var scale = Math.min( availableImageWidth / imageWidth, availableImageHeight / imageHeight);

       // Set new image dimensions
       $("#myImage").width(imageWidth * scale);
       $("#myImage").height(imageHeight * scale);
   }
   ```
2. You can do this by overriding the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method of the `WebViewClient` class:

   ```
   myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
   {
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
       {           
           // Redirect HTTP and HTTPS urls to the external browser
           if (url != null && URLUtil.isHttpUrl(url) || URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(url))
           {
               view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
               return true;
           }

           return false;
        }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To make the image fit on the screen, simply check the window's width and compare it with the image's width in the javascript on you web page. If the image's width is greater than the screen's width, set the image's width to the window's width.

Check out jQuery's [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function. You can use `$(window).width()` and `$('#myimageid").width()`.

As for opening a link in a WebView, the default behavior is open it using the user's default browser (NOT your WebView). If you want to override this behavior, check out [WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrl(WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)